# Integration question for finance (deriving the continuous Kelly Criterion)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm attempting to re-teach myself calculus for some finance work, and I'm currently stuck trying to understand a derivation within a book. Im finding some parts very difficult.

I do not understand how he gets from 8.11 to 8.12. My understanding is he takes the derivative and sets = 0 to find the value of f that maximizes the function, but I dont get the intermediary steps. What rules is he using t get from 8.11 to 8.12? Is this integration by parts?

[image]

Please help!

Comment: I rhink it's $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\int \ln(1+f\cdot g(x))\Phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

Comment: Thank you, I do understand that.  But where I get lost is the calculation that takes me from there to 8.12

Comment: Also it maybe should be somehow obvious that $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\Phi(x)=0$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}(\ln(1+fg(x))\Phi(x))=$ $\Phi(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial f}(\ln(1+fg(x)))=$ [chain rule] $\Phi(x)\dfrac{\frac{\partial}{\partial f}(1+fg(x))}{1+fg(x)}=$ $\Phi(x)\dfrac{g(x)}{1+fg(x)}$